# Accessing modem hard drive

Tags: networking, remote-access, modem

I was just curious, if it is possible? I mean, for some reason I would like to edit couple files. Html or css or even asp. I double checked that they are inside that modem.

I tried using filezilla using my remote access ip but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Model:
Telewell - TW-EA510v3(b)

Comment: Please clarify your actual intent. Also, what is the exact model of the modem you're trying to modify? Generally, one would need to build a complete firmware image.

Comment: Telewell - TW-EA510v3(b)

Comment: I have never heard of a modem with a hdd.  Please provide the English specifications on the device I was unable to locate the drive in a google search

Comment: Im not sure does it certainly have HDD, but something is stored to that thing and I have no clue is it even possible to access.

Comment: Maybe it is in flash memory or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any resources on how to replace the manufacturer's firmware. This means the device is probably not using open source components.

It all boils down to this: **No**, you won't be able to do anything. The firmware is typically stored in a read-only compressed image on the device's internal flash memory. This image also contains the web GUI.

Comment: It's probably impossible, yeah. I'm closing this one.